# How do I reconcile the Dhamma Refuge with blind faith?

Tags: refuge, faith

I read in Wikipedia and also in the suttas that refuge in Dhamma is "verified", as follows:

> Svakkhato Bhagavata dhammo sanditthiko akaliko ehipassiko opanayiko
>   paccattam vedittabbo vinnuhiti.
>
> "Svakkhato" The Dhamma taught by the Blessed One is Excellent in the
>   beginning, Excellent in the middle and Excellent in the end - all of
>   Buddha's Discourses are consistent and teach the same truth.
>   "Sanditthika" Dhamma is self-evident and can be understood in this
>   life itself. "Akaliko" Dhamma, Noble Truths, can not be changed nor
>   can they be altered over time. "Ehipassiko" "come and see"; Buddha's
>   Dhamma is to be investigated. "Opanayika" Dhamma can only be
>   understood by oneself. "Paccattam vedittabbo vinnuhiti" Dhamma is for
>   the wise to understand and realize.
>
> ---
>
> The teaching is well explained by the Buddha—visible in this very
>   life, immediately effective, inviting inspection, relevant, so that
>   sensible people can know it for themselves.
>
> svākkhāto bhagavatā dhammo sandiṭṭhiko akāliko ehipassiko opaneyyiko
>   paccattaṃ veditabbo viññūhīti.

Can I believe in things I have not verified for myself but still be a Buddhist?

Do the words "veditabbo viññūhīti" refer to direct experience? Or can it be merely  fluency in theories?

Comment: I guess you're quoting https://dhammawiki.com/index.php/Homage_to_the_Buddha,_Dhamma,_Sangha#Homage_to_the_Dhamma

Comment: I thought [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3694/254), about "Faith in Early Buddhism" as it's described in the canon, was informative.

Answer (score 2):

One can be a Buddhist:

- one believes in what is consistent with the teaching

  - verified by oneself
  - unverified but believed due to the confidence in the teaching

If one believes what is consistent even it is unverified there is no harm.