# Losing faith in tibetan buddhism

Tags: tibetan-buddhism

I have been practising tibetan buddhism for the past seven years and I am losing faith now and it hurts. I don't know what to do. Can someone advise?

Comment: Faith in Tibetan Buddhism? Or faith in Buddhism? Which it is will affect the answer.

Comment: A good talk on it: [The Buddha’s Relationship Advice](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/lib/authors/thanissaro/dhammatalks/index)

Comment: Care to elaborate on the root cause to why you lose your faith?

Comment: Are you thinking about the unfortunate situation with Shambhala International and the misdeeds of the Sakyong and failure of leadership? Or is there another issue that's coming up for you?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to buddhism.stackexchange. If you could elaborate on your question, it would make it easier for others to provide a proper answer for you and everyone else reading.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from people's comments (non-answer) it's hard to answer this question -- not specific enough -- it's phrased as an own-problem without enough detail about its cause or symptoms or the range of acceptable solutions.

Your mentioning "faith" though reminds me of this topic -- [What are the differences/similarities in the concept of faith as used in Buddhism and Christianity?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3681/254) -- because it seems to me that Buddhism doesn't have much to to do with "faith" as I understand that word -- maybe it's more to do with "knowledge" (whereas "faith" it sometimes denotes an opposite or absence of knowledge). So almost the opposite of some expressions of Christian doctrine, I think that Buddhism is based on "what you *know for yourself* to be true" (not only "faith"), which is an attribute of the Dhamma.

> The Dhamma is well declared by the Bhagavā:
>   visible here and now, immediate,
>   inviting to come and see, effective,
>   to be individually ascertained by the wise.

One example is [AN 3.66](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.066.nymo.html), but the rest of it too, I think that true of all the stages.

Christianity to me only makes sense to the extent that its values are embodied in someone -- if you meet someone who acts like a Christian -- maybe that was an essential part of that religion, starting with the Christ being a person.
Quite possibly some forms of Buddhism (relationship with a teacher, maybe learning from experience) might be like that too.

I'm guessing that "loss of faith" might have one of three causes:

- Believing in or having faith in a doctrine -- something supernatural perhaps -- without that doctrine's really making sense to you
- Ditto having faith in some *practice*
- Ditto having faith in some *person* or *society*

There are any number of possible remedies, I imagine:

- Improve your understanding of the doctrine, ask questions perhaps
- Improve -- or return to -- your practice, starting with "right view" perhaps

I can't tell you much about Tibetan Buddhism -- which is the only *other* part of your question. I understand it might involve some personal relationship (with a teacher) therefore possibly vulnerable to the third type of "loss of faith" listed above.

There are dozens of topics on this site which might be related to 'faith' -- [see here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=faith+is%3Aquestion) -- you could browse those titles, to see whether any of those are asking what you're asking and might have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Buddhism now a day have many branches mahayana,zen, and ofcourse tibetian.But if u have research on early buddhist texts and lord buddha's life story u will understand ur self what content of buddhism is true and what content of buddhism forge  after the passing of Lord Buddha.As in Buddha's own words ..........

“Do not believe in anything simply because you have heard it. Do not believe in anything simply because it is spoken and rumored by many. Do not believe in anything simply because it is found written in your religious books. Do not believe in anything merely on the authority of your teachers and elders. Do not believe in traditions because they have been handed down for many generations. But after observation and analysis, when you find that anything agrees with reason and is conducive to the good and benefit of one and all, then accept it and live up to it.”

As u can see faith that have without a root is useless and will not last long.So if u want to build up a strong faith about Buddhism u have learn,research, and analyzes ur self  until u believe and accept with reasons and results that Dharma is true.

(As above Quote says Dont believe my answer simply u feel it right But after observation and analysis, when you find that anything agrees with reason and is conducive to the good and benefit of one and all)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question. Tibetan buddhism ? What is it? Why there’s another word before buddhism ?

The original buddhism has changed according to some people's perceptions. After that there are many flavours of buddhism available today.

You may try to find the core of the original buddhism instead of finding which buddhism is the correct one. Once you find the correct one you will feel the difference.

Comment: Thank you everyone! You guys are so wonderful!